# Jenkins Server Java.exe memory is growing very fast

Tags: memory, jenkins

We're running Jenkins server with few slaves that run the builds. Lately there are more and more builds that are running in the same time.
I see the java.exe process on the Jenkins server just increasing , and not decreasing even when the jobs were finnished.

Any idea dwhy oes it happen?

We're running Jenkins ver. 1.501.

Is there a way maybe to make the Jenkins server service ro wait until the last job is finnished, then restart automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find a reference on this (still posting an answer because it's too long for comments ;-) ) but this is what I've observed using the Oracle JVM:

If more memory than currently reserved is needed, the JVM reserves more. So far so good. What it doesn't seem to do is release the memory once it's not needed anymore. You can watch this behaviour by turning on the heap size indicator in Eclipse.

I'd say the same does happen with Jenkins. A running Jenkins with only a few projects already can easily jump the 1 gig mark. If you have a lot of concurrent builds, Jenkins needs a lot of memory at some point. After the builds are done and the heapsize has decreased, the JVM keeps the memory reserved. It is practically "empty" but still claimed by the JVM so it's unavailable for other processes.

Again: It's just an observation. I'd be happy if someone with deeper insight on Java memory management would back this up (or disprove it)

As for a practical solution I'd say you gonna have to live with it to some point. Jenkins IS very hungry for memory. Restarting it solves the problem only temporary. At least it should stop claiming memory at some point because the "empty" reserved memory should be reused. If it's not this really sounds like a memory leak and would be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins' [excessive] use of memory without bounds seems to be a common observation.  The Jenkins Wiki gives some suggestions for "[I'm getting OutOfMemoryErrors](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/I%27m+getting+OutOfMemoryError)".

We have also found that the [Monitoring Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring) is useful for keeping an eye on the memory usage and helping us know if we might need to restart Jenkins soon.

> Is there a way maybe to make the Jenkins server service ro wait until the last job is finnished, then restart automatically?

Check out the [Restart Safely Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SafeRestart+Plugin)